# Why does my expanded container not take up the remaining height of my device?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following along this tutorial and I ran into a problem. I have a main container and within the main container there's a column. Inside the column, there are various elements and at the end there's an extended container that creates an overlapping effect. However, the problem is that the extended container does not cover the remaining rest of the device height, and it leaves a space towards the end showing the background of the parent container. I'm new to flutter so I'm now learning the syntax, I've tried doubling the height of the expanded container but that did not work. How can I fix this?

[image: image showing how the expanded container is displaying on the screen]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            colors: [
              Colors.blue[900],
              Colors.blue[500],
              Colors.blue[400],
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 40.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Eazy",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Bank",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0)`, the `padding` takes a value of `30.0 logical pixels` for both vertical directions(top and down).

You can fix that by using the `padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0)` which only gives padding to the `top` of the container.

I added a demo using your widget tree as an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0), // new line
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            colors: [
              Colors.blue[900],
              Colors.blue[500],
              Colors.blue[400],
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 40.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Eazy",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Bank",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```